# Sales of car radios

Tags: algebra-precalculus

An electronics store put two types of car radios on sale. One model sold for \$87 and the other sold for \$119 dollars. During the sale the receipts for 25 dollars radios sold were \$2,495 how many of the less expensive radio?

Comment: Is the word "dollars" after 25 not supposed to be there?

Answer (score 2):

Removing the word "dollars" from the question, it looks like there were a total of $25$ radios sold.  If there were $x$ sold at  $\$87$ and $y$ sold at $\$119$, the total income was $87x+119y$.  This gives $x+y=25, 87x+119y=2495$